# HTML email with attachments

Tags: html, email, mime, uuencode

A friend of mine wants me to help him make a HTML email template that contains a header and footer image.

Originally I thought it would be easy enough to just create a tabular html email that used remote images inside  tags for the header and footer, however most email clients will not display these images by default.

A collegue has mentioned MIME and UUEncoding, however I cannot find a clear example of how to achieve this.

Could somebody please give me a hint on how I can achieve what it is I am trying to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Modern MIME messages use `base64`, not `uuencode`.  Anyway, use a tool which does the job for you, especially if you are unfamiliar with MIME.  You don't tell us which programming language you plan to use, so this isn't really even an acceptable question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as tripleee wrote, you have to use some library or client which understands MIME.

Include the HTML body and the referenced images in a multipart/related MIME part.

Refer the images in the HTML part using the cid protocol. For example

> <img src="cid:logo">.

Here is an example MIME header for the included picture:

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=logo.jpg 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=logo.jpg
Content-ID: logo
```